# My generated link in the unordered list is not navigable

Tags: javascript, json

```js
let x=[];
let array = []
const json1 = '{"https://www.w3schools.com/html/":"check w3 schools"}';
const obj1 = JSON.parse(json1);
array=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1);
    ul = document.createElement('ul');
            ser.appendChild(ul);
                    x= document.createElement('li');
                    x.innerText="<a href=\"" + array[0]+ "\">"+"</a>";//hyper link not clickable
                    ul.appendChild(x);
```

```html
<div id="ser"></div>
```

the javascript code renders the unordered list but the link  in the list() is not navigable.Please advice on solving this issue.

Comment: `innerText` sets _text_. Use `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: used innerHTML , and the link in the unordered list completely disappears..

Comment: You also need to add some text inside the tag - `<a href="...">link text here</a>`

Comment: Because there's no text in the `<a></a> tag.

Comment: i put console.log(x); before the /script tag and the <a></a> tag in the console is :<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/"></a>

Comment: But there's no text inside the `a` tag to be rendered as the link. You would need `<a href="w3schools.com/html/">W3Schools</a>` to have the link show up and be rendered as "W3Schools"

Comment: so Thanks this solved it  x.innerHTML="<a href=\"" + array[0]+ "\">w3schools"+"</a>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple fixes so take a look at this

```
let array = []
const json1 = '{"https://www.w3schools.com/html/":"check w3 schools"}';
const obj1 = JSON.parse(json1);
array = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1);
const ul = document.querySelector('#ser').appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
const x = document.createElement('li');
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute("href", array[0]);
a.innerHTML = array[0];
x.appendChild(a);
ul.appendChild(x);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I see the new queryselector approach

Answer (score 0):

You must use `.innerHTML` instead of `.innerText`.
Also, make sure to put text inside the  and  tags, or else the link won't be visible.

Comment: Thanks ,yes there was some missing text so I changed to x.innerHTML="<a href=\"" + array[0]+ "\">w3schools"+"</a>" and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).